# Can't acces website when ssl enabled

Tags: apache, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

We're trying to use SSL on our website. 
The website is on a ubuntu server 2016. I've generated certicates from let's encrypt and followed the ubuntu tutorial but at the end i'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.eu
    ServerName dp7.sitename.eu
    ServerAlias www.dp7.sitename.eu

    #SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/cert.pem
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/fullchain.pem
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/privkey.pem
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bt750
        <Directory "/var/www/bt750">
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dp7_ssl_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dp7_ssl_access.log "combined"
</VirtualHost>
```

i have flushed all my chrome cache, without success

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in apache configuration. You need `Listen` the 443 port and uncomment SLL configuration

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.eu
    ServerName dp7.sitename.eu
    ServerAlias www.dp7.sitename.eu

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.fr/privkey.pem
        DocumentRoot /var/www/bt750
        <Directory "/var/www/bt750">
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dp7_ssl_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dp7_ssl_access.log "combined"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, sadly it didn't worked, im getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on my browser.

Comment: My error log is empty.
/var/log/apache2/dp7_ssl_error.log is empty.
The /var/log/apache2/error.log contains : 
`[Mon Jan 02 06:28:18.619197 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30653] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations`

and 

`[Mon Jan 02 06:28:18.619220 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30653] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: The log  dont say anything. May be en error with domain? You have `.fr` in directory an `.eu` in server name. Also you can analyze the server in ssllabs.com

Comment: Thanks  i finally managed to get the ssl up and running. ssllabs.com saved me. Sadly i can't upvote you, i need more réputation.